# Access Variable in CFC using URL Invocation Method

Tags: coldfusion, scope, instance, cfc

I've a variable in my Application.cfm that stores the datasource for cfqueries.

```
<cfset mydatasource= 'somedatasorce'>
```

I can use it in any normal cfm page as below:

```
<cfset any_var = #mydatasource#>
```

I've a cfm page that calls a cfc which builds a query dynamically. This is the URL Invocation Method of CFC.

I'm not able to access "mydatasource" in the CFC using the above statement. It says "mydatasource" is undefined. I tried storing this in Application scope & accessed in CFC but again it says "mydatasource" is undefined in "Application".

On a bit of search, I found that the CFC needs to be instantiated in order to access the Application scope. But the URL Invocation method doesn't create an instance.

I can pass the datasource using query string but I'm looking for a better & more secure alternative.

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks!! :)

Comment: What version of ColdFusion are you using? In ColdFusion 9+ you can use `this.datasource = 'dsname'`  in Application.cfc to set a 'default' datasource that will be used with any `cfquery` or ORM operation.

Comment: "I found that the CFC needs to be instantiated in order to access the Application scope. But the URL Invocation method doesn't create an instance." Where'd you read that? I'm fairly sure it's not true. However @ScottStroz's answer is perhaps the preferable approach here.

Comment: Its CF9 but I can't use Application.CFC file. Can we set the datasource in Application.cfm file?

Comment: Not sure. Try it and let us know if it works. BTW - why, in the name of all that is holy, are you using CF9 and NOT using Application.cfc?

Comment: Now that I think about it, I am fairly sure that `this.datasource` will only work in Application.cfc. Another thing you could try in Application.cfm is to set `request.datasource`, you should be able to access that in the CFC being called remotely.

Comment: Thanks for the help Scott. request.datasource didn't work. Ok, so let me try converting my already present Application.cfm to Application.cfc. There are some variables & <cfscript> blocks in application.cfm file. But I'm not sure about their scope. Where should I put the same in Application.cfc? Shall it be outside <cffunction> tags or inside onRequestStart function?

Comment: It depends on what the code is for, honestly.

Answer (score 1):

I have been adding a number of ajax calls to an old application here and in order to get some application specific settings I created a file I called App.cfc.  The contents of it are simply:

```
<cfcomponent>
<cfscript>
this["datasource"] = "something";
..... and so on .....
</cfscript>
</cfcomponent>
```

Then the CFC files I am making my URL calls to they simple extend App.  So within those CFCs I can do `datasource="#this['Datasource']#"`

May not be the most "pretty" of ways to get the job done but it has been working here without issues.

**UPDATE**

I should have also mentioned that in order to avoid having settings in both that CFC and in the Application.cfm, I have something like this in my Application.cfm:

```
<cfscript>
objApp = CreateObject("component", "Components.App");
StructAppend(App, objApp);
</cfscript>
```

These old applications I am working with have a structure withing VARIABLES called App that is a copy of all Application variables.  I see no reason why in this case you could not just do a structure appending to VARIABLES since appears that is where you are expecting things like the datasource to be on in your CFM pages.

Comment: Ugly people like me think that being pretty is overrated.